# Is it possible to fix parameter min.insync.replicas across kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

I mean that I want to hardcode this param to be visible across cluster and want to ensure that no one will override this param during topic creation or any other way on the fly. Or maybe other workaround which will not allow anyone doing such thing. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible by implementing the 2 following custom policies:

- [CreateTopicPolicy](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/policy/CreateTopicPolicy.html)
- [AlterConfigPolicy](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/policy/AlterConfigPolicy.html)

These policies allow you to validate configurations applied to topics when they are created and altered. If some configurations are not accepted, throw a `PolicyViolationException` to reject them.

To enable custom policies, you need to set the following broker settings:

- [create.topic.policy.class.name](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_create.topic.policy.class.name)
- [alter.config.policy.class.name](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_alter.config.policy.class.name)